# How do I install Caliburn.Micro using Nuget

Tags: caliburn.micro

When I try to install it with "Install-Package Caliburn.Micro.Start" I get the following:

```
PM> Install-Package Caliburn.Micro.Start
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Caliburn.Micro (= 2.0.2)'.
Install-Package : 'Caliburn.Micro' already has a dependency defined for 'Caliburn.Micro.Core'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Caliburn.Micro.Start
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package],         InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :         NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

And when I try "Install-Package Caliburn.Micro" I get:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Caliburn.Micro.Core (= 2.0.2)'.
Install-Package : 'Caliburn.Micro' already has a dependency defined for 'Caliburn.Micro.Core'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Caliburn.Micro
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Is there a correct way to install this? Is it even maintained anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that Caliburn Micro doesn't install on a stock version of Visual Studio 2012. You *must* update Visual Studio and get a newer version of Nuget to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the package version (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro):

```
Install-Package Caliburn.Micro -Version 2.0.2
```

This is my log:

```
PM> Install-Package Caliburn.Micro -Version 2.0.2
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Caliburn.Micro.Core (= 2.0.2)'.
Installing 'Caliburn.Micro.Core 2.0.2'.
Successfully installed 'Caliburn.Micro.Core 2.0.2'.
Installing 'Caliburn.Micro 2.0.2'.
Successfully installed 'Caliburn.Micro 2.0.2'.
Adding 'Caliburn.Micro.Core 2.0.2' to WpfApplication1.
Successfully added 'Caliburn.Micro.Core 2.0.2' to WpfApplication1.
Adding 'Caliburn.Micro 2.0.2' to WpfApplication1.
Successfully added 'Caliburn.Micro 2.0.2' to WpfApplication1.
```

Comment: I tried exactly what you wrote and got exactly the same error message as before. If i try install Caliburn.Micro.Core then it installs to a specific version, but the other two packages won't install. Can you install Caliburn.Micro.Start?

Comment: Yes, I can. `PM> Install-Package Caliburn.Micro.Start -Version 2.0.2` works fine.

Comment: I use `VS Professional 2013` and `NuGet Package Manager  2.8.50313.46`